# GPU monitoring doesn't work in Android Studio 1.4

Tags: android, android-studio, gpu, monitoring

I updated today the IDE to the 1.4 version. I read in the changelog about now there is a new GPU Rendering Monitor aviable in the Android Monitor view.

So I did what the documentation says:

> To enable GPU monitoring, make sure you turn on monitoring for your Android hardware device or emulator under Setting → Developer Options → Profile GPU rendering → In adb shell dumpsys gfxinfo

And... nothing happens. I don't know why because documentation also says:

> To learn more about the GPU rendering results, check out the developer documentation.

But that "developer documentation" isn't updated, so it doesn't say anything about GPU monitoring at all.

Howerver, the new Network monitoring is working fine untill now. I'm using a Nexus 5 5.1.1 by the way.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Same problem here. I get either nothing, or a couple of sporadic data points just after app startup followed by no data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One you enabled GPU rendering in adb shell dumpsys gfxinfo, you have to untoggle the pause icon in Android Studio (on the left of the graph) for the GPU profiling to start for the selected app.

Bye,
JB.

Comment: It was that! Thank you!

Comment: I'm working on a LibGDX project, but I can't see the GPU networking even though profiling is unpaused. Any idea how to solve this? I can see a spike at first when the app is loaded, but then nothing.